# Javascript OOP & Coffe

Tags: javascript, oop, coffeescript

I'm trying to understand the way OOP is handled in Javascript and I stumbled upon the way coffescript definies the constructor function and the prototype.
Can somebody tell me what's the advantage of this code

```
Animal = (function() {

  function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  Animal.prototype.move = function(meters) {
    return alert(this.name + (" moved " + meters + "m."));
  };

  return Animal;

})();
```

compared to this

```
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.move = function(meters) {
  return alert(this.name + (" moved " + meters + "m."));
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example has an anonymous self executing function wrapping the Animal object.

In the example given this does not provide an additional encapsulation.
However normally you might want to return a more complex object or rely on additional variables which would be declared in the global scope (a bad thing).